# can you suppress the "Duplicate Mark" prompt in Revit during c# program?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a program that sets "Mark" parameter values, unique for each "identical" beam or column.  This usually results in more than one beam with the same "Mark" parameter, and Revit displays the odd "Warning - can be ignored.......Elements have duplicate 'Mark' values" (odd because it cannot really be ignored, because it always displays).

Does anyone know how to turn off this warning during the execution of a program?  I will likely be collecting additional element types (such as connections, stiffeners, or even foundations) and assigning "Mark" parameters, and it would be nice to avoid having that warning appear 4 or 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty straight forward. You can use something called `IFailurePreprocessor` to catch all of these warnings and dismiss them from code:

Create a preprocessor class:

```
public class DuplicateMarkSwallower : IFailuresPreprocessor
{
    public FailureProcessingResult PreprocessFailures(FailuresAccessor a)
    {
        var failures = a.GetFailureMessages();
        foreach (var f in failures)
        {
            var id = f.GetFailureDefinitionId();
            if (BuiltInFailures.GeneralFailures.DuplicateValue == id)
            {
                a.DeleteWarning(f);
            }
        }
        return FailureProcessingResult.Continue;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
using (var trans = new Transaction(_doc, "Creating Numbers"))
{
    trans.Start();

    // Set failure handler
    var failureOptions = trans.GetFailureHandlingOptions();
    failureOptions.SetFailuresPreprocessor(new DuplicateMarkSwallower());
    trans.SetFailureHandlingOptions(failureOptions);

    // do your thing here

    trans.Commit();
}
```